# I can’t figure out why my code is not displaying palindromes. Is is saying NO for everything when it should be saying Yes if it’s a palindrome

Tags: arrays, assembly, mips, palindrome

```
.org 0x10000000

# Initializations
# NOTE: You may add initializations after line 10, but please do not
# remove or change the initializations to $sp, $s0, $s1, or $s2

li $sp, 0x10fffffc # Starting address of empty stack
li $s0, 0xf0000000 # UART base address
li $s1, array_ptr # Array head pointer
li $s2, array_ptr # Array tail pointer
li $t8  0x00000000

####################################################################
# Do not make changes to the jump to main, the allocation of
# memory for the array, or the main loop
####################################################################
j main
nop

array_ptr: # Label pointing to 100 word array
.space 100

main:
jal poll_UART
nop
jal period_check
nop
jal space_check
nop
jal case_check
nop
jal array_push
nop
j main
nop
####################################################################
# ******************************************************************
####################################################################


# The "poll_UART" function should poll the status register of the UART.
# If the 2^1 bit position (ready bit) is set to 1 then it
# should copy the receive buffer's value into $v0 and send
# a clear status command (2^1) to the command register before
# returning (a return statement is already included). In order to
# receive full credit, $s0 must contain the base address of the UART
# and must be used with the appropriate offsets to access UART
# registers and buffers

poll_UART:
lw $t1, 4($s0)
li $t2, 0b10
and $t3, $t1, $t2
beq $t3, $0, main
nop
lw $v0, 8($s0)
sw $t2, 0($s0)


jr $ra
nop

# The "period_check" function should check if the current character ($v0)
# is a period ("."). If it is a period then the function should go to the
# label, "palindrome_check". If the character is not a period then it
# should use the included return.

period_check:
li $t0, 0x2E
beq $v0, $t0, palindrome_check
   nop


jr $ra
nop

# The "space_check" function should check if the current character ($v0)
# is a space (" "). If it is then it should jump to "main" so
# that it skips saving the space character. If not it should
# use the included return.

space_check:
li $t4, 0x20
beq $t4, $v0, main
nop


jr $ra
nop

# The "case_check" function should perform a single inequality check.
# If the current character ($v0) is greater than the ASCII value of 'Z',
# which indicates the current character is lowercase, then it should convert
# the value of $v0 to the uppercase equivalent and then return. If the
# current character ($v0) is already uppercase (meaning the inequality
# mentioned before was not true) then the function should return without
# performing a conversion.

case_check:
li $t5, 0x5A
   slt $t6, $v0, $t5
   li $t7, 1
   beq $t6, $t7, change_uppercase

change_uppercase:
   addiu $v0, $v0, -32

jr $ra
nop


# The "array_push" function should save the current character ($v0) to the
# current location of the tail pointer, $s2. Then it should increment the
# tail pointer so that it points to the next element of the array. Last
# it should use the included return statement.

array_push:
sw $v0, 0($s2)
addiu $s2, $s2, 4


jr $ra
nop

# The "palindrome_check" subroutine should be jumped to by the period
# check function if a period is encountered. This subroutine should contain
# a loop that traverses the array from the front towards the back (using the
# head pointer, $s1) and from the back towards the front(using the tail
# pointer, $s2). If the string is a palindrome then as the array is traversed
# the characters pointed to should be equal. If the characters are not equal
# then the string is not a palindrome and the print function should be used
# to print "No". If the pointers cross (i.e. the head pointer's address is
# greater than or equal to the tail pointer's address) and the compared
# characters are equal then the string is a palindrome and "Yes" should be
# printed.
#
# Remember to restore the head and tail pointers to the first element
# of the array before the subroutine jumps back to main to begin processing the
# next string. Also, keep in mind that because the tail pointer is updated at
# the end of "array_push" it technically points one element past the last
# character in the array. You will need to compensate for this by either
# decrementing the pointer once at the start of the array or using an offset
# from this pointer's address.

palindrome_check:
addiu $s2, $s2, -8
   move $s3, $s1
   subu $s4, $s2, $s3
   beq $s4, $0, palindrome
   nop
check_loop:
   lw $s5, 0($s3)
   lw $s6, 0($s2)
   bne $s6, $t5, not_palindrome
   nop
adjust_pointers:
   addiu $s2, $s2, -4
   addiu $s3, $s3, 4
   slt $t8, $s3, $s2
   bne $t8, $0, check_loop
   nop
   j palindrome
   nop
palindrome:
   li $a0, 1
   call project3_print
   move $s2, $s1
   j main
nop
not_palindrome:
   li $a0, 0
   call project3_print
   move $s2, $s1


j main
nop
```

I have tried working on debugging the Palindrome check and everything under that but it all appears fine. Im not sure if the problem remains in the poll_uart or not. this is the template I was given.

When I type in racecar it says no. when I type in gn. it says yes. when I type in night. it says no. So I am just confused.

Comment: `addiu $s2, $s2, -8` ... why? Also `bne $s6, $t5, not_palindrome` should probably be `$s5`. Use your debugger to single step the code.

Comment: # Decrement $s2 by two words to get the address of last letter in the string. I have single stepped the code. every word is going to not palindrome unless its a double letter word. My professor is vague and has not taught us anything.

Comment: Why two words? I would expect 1 word ... since, as the helpful comment says: _"keep in mind that [...] the tail pointer [...] points one element past the last character in the array."_ Anyway, single stepping should show you what characters are compared so you can verify it easily.